# Can't access onPressed method of a Widget when creating it dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

First of all, let me fill you in the details:

I have this `Widget`:

```js
class MenuAction extends StatelessWidget {
  const MenuAction({
    Key? key,
    this.height,
    required this.icon,
    required this.label,
    required this.willNavigate,
    this.route,
    this.onPressed,
    required this.identifier,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? height;
  final IconData icon;
  final String label;
  final bool willNavigate;
  final Widget? route;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final String identifier;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 70,
      height: height ?? 80,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ClipOval(
            child: Material(
              color: Palette.aliceBlue,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  increaseUsage(identifier: identifier);

                  willNavigate ? navigate(context, route) : onPressed;
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  icon,
                  color: Palette.celticBlue,
                  size: 25,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          Text(
            label,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Palette.oxfordBlue,
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          const Spacer(
            flex: 3,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This widget must have an `icon`, a `label`, an `identifier` and it should be specified if this widget `willNavigate` to a route or not.

If it should navigate, a `route` should be specified. If it shouldn't navigate, a `onPressed` function should be specific.

I also have a list of predefined actions built:

```js
List<MenuAction> actions = [
  MenuAction(
    icon: Icons.cloud_download_outlined,
    label: "Sincronizar",
    willNavigate: false,
    onPressed: () async {},
    identifier: "syncDat",
  ),
  MenuAction(
    icon: Icons.business_center_outlined,
    label: "Proposta Comercial",
    willNavigate: true,
    route: AppRoutes.comercialProposalList,
    identifier: "propCom",
  ),
  MenuAction(
    icon: Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
    label: "Pedidos",
    willNavigate: true,
    route: AppRoutes.orderList,
    identifier: "order",
  ),
  MenuAction(
    icon: Icons.cloud_upload_outlined,
    label: "Enviar Pedidos",
    willNavigate: false,
    onPressed: () {},
    identifier: "sendOrd",
  ),
  MenuAction(
    icon: Icons.receipt_long_rounded,
    label: "Nota Fiscal",
    willNavigate: true,
    route: AppRoutes.invoiceList,
    identifier: "invoice",
  ),
  MenuAction(
    icon: Icons.person_outline,
    label: "Clientes",
    willNavigate: true,
    route: AppRoutes.clientsList,
    identifier: "clients",
  ),
  MenuAction(
    icon: Icons.map_outlined,
    label: "Endereços",
    willNavigate: true,
    route: AppRoutes.addressesList,
    identifier: "address",
  ),
  MenuAction(
    icon: Icons.inventory_2_outlined,
    label: "Estoque",
    willNavigate: true,
    route: AppRoutes.inventoryList,
    identifier: "invent",
  ),
];
```

I access these actions through this function:

```js
MenuAction getActionByIdentifier({String identifier = ""}) {
  return actions.elementAt(
    actions.indexWhere((element) => element.identifier == identifier),
  );
}
```

Why go through all this trouble to create some simple widgets? they'll be used at my app's home screen, where all actions will be available in a horizontal slider. Also, the most used actions will be displayed below to the user. A count of how many times said action was used is stored in my local database along with the action's identifier, allowing me to retrieve and create it later using the function described earlier. Why did I did it this way? because I wanted to code my action only once and access it from different sources.

Now, if I create my actions statically, their `onPressed` event works flawlessly.

This is the Widget that creates all my actions statically:

```js
class HomeActionsListView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeActionsListView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeActionsListView> createState() => _HomeActionsListViewState();
}

class _HomeActionsListViewState extends State<HomeActionsListView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: [
        getActionByIdentifier(identifier: "syncDat"),
        getActionByIdentifier(identifier: "propCom"),
        getActionByIdentifier(identifier: "order"),
        getActionByIdentifier(identifier: "sendOrd"),
        getActionByIdentifier(identifier: "invoice"),
        getActionByIdentifier(identifier: "clients"),
        getActionByIdentifier(identifier: "address"),
        getActionByIdentifier(identifier: "invent"),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `onPressed` event is **ALWAYS** present within my widget, since ALL actions increase their usage count in the database. As you can see in the code, the `increaseUsage` is called and then the widget will decide if it will only navigate to the provided `route` OR execute the specified custom `onPressed` function.

But for some reason, when I create the same widgets using the `getActionByIdentifier` function and try to pass it's `label` and `onPressed` event to a custom `Card` I built, the event doesn't trigger.

This is the FutureBuilder that creates my cards dynamically within a ListView based on the first most used actions:

```js
FutureBuilder(
  future: getMostUsedActions(),
  builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            MenuAction action = getActionByIdentifier(
              identifier: snapshot.data![index],
            );

            return RecentActionCard(
              text: action.label,
              onPressed: action.onPressed,
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return const Center(
          heightFactor: 15,
          child: Text(
            "Nenhuma ação utilizada recentemente!",
          ),
        );
      }
    } else {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
      );
    }
  },
);
```

This is the code to my custom `Card`:

```js
class RecentActionCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const RecentActionCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        side: BorderSide(
          color: Palette.celticBlue,
          width: 2,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                  child: Text(
                    text,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Barlow",
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Palette.oxfordBlue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 55,
                width: 55,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: onPressed,
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                    color: Palette.oxfordBlue,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, my question is: Why do my statically created widget's onPressed event work and when I try to create them dinamically they are returned as null?

Also, any way to make it work?

And, last but not least, if you have any suggestions on how to improve my code, they'll be much appreciated.